# JavaScript raphael circle element 

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am a newbie to Raphael lib, my question is following:

can I use path specific methods (like `getTotalLength()` or `getPointAtLength()`) for a circle element - this would be quite helpfull (and at the begining I thought that circle somehow inherits from path - so that should be possible... but it simply does not work :( ), ie.

```
var cir = paper.circle(100, 100, 20);
var totalength=cir.getTotalLength();
paper.text(50,150,'Length=('+totalength+')',20);
var pt = cir.getPointAtLength(0);
paper.text(50,250,'Point=('+pt.x+','+pt.y+')',20);
```

thanks for any comments/hints/explanations on that,
Borys

Comment: I understand the total length thing, but from which starting point should getPointAtLength() count?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you cannot.  Circle is its own svg element.  It wouldn't be too hard to write some functions that replicate these path-specific actions:

getTotalLength:

```
2*pi*radius
```

getPointAtLength:
You'd have to figure out where the circle's path 'starts', but with that set it's something like:

```
rad = (length / total_length) * 2*pi
y = center_y + (sin(rad) * radius)
x = center_x + (cos(rad) * radius)
```

Comment: thanks for this info, I got to the point that it is fairly easy to draw the cicrle with a use of a "path" and this is most suitable